# Syntax for adding multiple custom headers in IIS 'set config'

Tags: iis, http-headers, config

I have the following IIS config as part of a Release pipline:

```
set config "$(WebsiteName)$(WebAppName)" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='Version-Info',value='$(Release.DefinitionName):$(Release.ReleaseName):$(Release.EnvironmentName)']"
```

How do I augment `customheaders` config such that I can stipulate multiple custom headers, rather that just the `Version-Info` below

```
customHeaders.[name='Version-Info',value='$(Release.DefinitionName):$(Release.ReleaseName):$(Release.EnvironmentName)']
```

Comment: I'm not  sure if I understand your issue correctly. IIS allow users add many custom headers and no need to add under `Version-Info`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/loZUo.png

Comment: Thanks @BruceZhang. The `Version-Info` was just an example of one of our custom headers. I was wondering how to change the above to include multiple headers. Sure, I can change IIS but I'd like it scripted out as per the above.

Comment: There's no way to add multiple headers in a command. The only way is execute the command for several times to add multiple headers.

Comment: @BruceZhang. Thanks. If you wanted to make that an answer then I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested different scripts to add headers in a command line. It seems that only way is execute the command for several times to add multiple headers.

**Appcmd**

```
appcmd.exe set config "a" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='header1',value='value1']" 

appcmd.exe set config "a" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='header2',value='value2']" 

appcmd.exe set config "a" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='header3',value='value3']"
```

**Powershell**

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/a'  -filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" -name "." -value @{name='header1';value='value1'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/a'  -filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" -name "." -value @{name='header2';value='value2'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/a'  -filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" -name "." -value @{name='header3';value='value3'}
```

**Javascript**

```
var adminManager = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager');
adminManager.CommitPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/a";

var httpProtocolSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/a");

var customHeadersCollection = httpProtocolSection.ChildElements.Item("customHeaders").Collection;

var addElement = customHeadersCollection.CreateNewElement("add");
addElement.Properties.Item("name").Value = "header1";
addElement.Properties.Item("value").Value = "value1";
customHeadersCollection.AddElement(addElement);


var addElement1 = customHeadersCollection.CreateNewElement("add");
addElement1.Properties.Item("name").Value = "header2";
addElement1.Properties.Item("value").Value = "value2";
customHeadersCollection.AddElement(addElement1);


var addElement2 = customHeadersCollection.CreateNewElement("add");
addElement2.Properties.Item("name").Value = "header3";
addElement2.Properties.Item("value").Value = "value3";
customHeadersCollection.AddElement(addElement2);


adminManager.CommitChanges();
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {
        
        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("a");
            
            ConfigurationSection httpProtocolSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol");
            
            ConfigurationElementCollection customHeadersCollection = httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders");
            
            ConfigurationElement addElement = customHeadersCollection.CreateElement("add");
            addElement["name"] = @"header1";
            addElement["value"] = @"value1";
            customHeadersCollection.Add(addElement);
            
            ConfigurationElement addElement1 = customHeadersCollection.CreateElement("add");
            addElement1["name"] = @"header2";
            addElement1["value"] = @"value2";
            customHeadersCollection.Add(addElement1);
            
            ConfigurationElement addElement2 = customHeadersCollection.CreateElement("add");
            addElement2["name"] = @"header3";
            addElement2["value"] = @"value3";
            customHeadersCollection.Add(addElement2);
            
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```